# Auto Layout - UIButton to bottom depending on UI objects in UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a problem with Auto Layout. In my `UIViewController` I have the following view hierarchy:

```
- View
-- Small Bar
-— Scroll View (leading, trailing, bottom to superview, top to Small Bar)
—-— Container View (leading, trailing, bottom and top spaces to superview)
———- UILabel
———- UITextField
———- UILabel
———- UITextField
———- UIButton (full width, top to UITextField, bottom to superview)
```

I want the UIButton to be always hooked to the bottom of the view, depending on the size of the screen. If, however, after rotating the screen, it will turn out that the button will cover other views, it will have constant about 30 from the last object in the hierarchy.

I've tried with relations between UITextField and UIButton with "Greater Than or Equal" - 20 constant, but it didn't work. I've tried messing with priority, but effect was the same.

Here are the screenshot :[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: I think this constraint is simply unsolvable, because bottom constraint is fixed. You would probably like to implement `updateViewConstraints` and manually replace or update button constraints on rotation.

Comment: I've wanted to do this only with Interface Bulider, but thanks to You I've figured it out programmatically. If no one will help me with IB, I will post my solution ;)

Comment: what you want is logic, IB does not provide logic, instead your controllers implement that.

Answer (score 0):

For making the bottom control to be stayed there always then scroll view should be inside a container view. 
Look at this view hierarchy:

```
-View
---BarView(Leading, trailing and top space to super view, Height)
--=ContainerView(leading, trailing, bottom space to superview, vertical space to BarView)
-----ScrollView(leading, trailing, top, bottom space to super view)
-------UILabel
-------UITextField
-------UILabel
-------UITextField
-------UIButton(leading, trailing to superview(ScrollView), Height, Bottom and Right to ContainerView)
```

It is working fine as you expected.
Refer this screene

[image]

Try it out.

Comment: Thanks! :) I've tried Your solution, button gets his place right, but when I want to hook up with other views (`UILabel`, `UITextField`), button covers them. When I connect views with auto layout i get ambiguous `UIScrollView`. I've learned that in iOS > 7.0 You need to implement `UIScrollView` in another view. Not the other way.